# Isolate $y$ (that is nested inside $ln$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to isolate y in this equation:
$$-4/3·\ln⁡(|y-60|)=x+c$$

If I use a cas-tool to isolate $y$, I get:

$$60.-(2.71828182846)^{−0.75*x-0.75*c}=y$$

If I try isolating $y$ by hand I get:

[image]

---

These two are not the same, is the cas-tool right or am I right? What are the rules to isolate something when the absolute value is taken of it as in this case.

---

Proof they are not equal: (black is my result, red is cas-tool's result)

[image]

Comment: Domain of $\ln$ is $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran What is your point? What is the correct result?

Comment: You have two cases; one where $y-60 = \ldots$ and $-(y-60)= \ldots$. Since htere is no requirement on $y$, consider these two cases in the context of the range of $x$ and the domain of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y>60$, then these are equivalent:
$$
-4/3·\ln⁡(|y-60|)=x+c \\
-4/3·\ln⁡(y-60)=x+c \\
\ln⁡(y-60)=\frac{-3(x+c)}{4} \\
y-60=\exp\frac{-3(x+c)}{4} \\
y=60+\exp\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}\\
$$
Similarly, if $y<60$,
$$
-4/3·\ln⁡(|y-60|)=x+c \\
-4/3·\ln⁡(60-y)=x+c \\
\ln⁡(60-y)=\frac{-3(x+c)}{4} \\
60-y=\exp\frac{-3(x+c)}{4} \\
y=60-\exp\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}\\
$$
Note the $2.71828$ in the cas answer is $e$, $0.75 = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\exp(z) = e^z$.  So the caz answer is my second solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, multiply everything by $\frac{-3}{4}$ to obtain 
$$\ln|y-60|=\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}$$
Now exponentiate everything: 
$$|y-60|$ = e^{\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}}$$
Now, we need to take cases, because of the absolute value sign (which is what you lost along the way in your derivation):

If $y > 60$, then 
$$y = 60 + e^{\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}}$$
which agrees exactly with your answer, because the absolute value sign that you lost doesn't matter in this case.

But if $y < 60$, then

$$y = 60 - e^{\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}}$$
which agrees with the value given by your CAS tool (up to the CAS tool's rounding). I assume that the CAS tool is assuming some default values of $y$ to address the absolute value sign. Probably $y = 0$ or something.

If you feel like putting everything into one expression, then, it's

$$y = 60+\mathrm{\mathop{sgn}}(y-60)e^\frac{-3(x+c)}{4}.$$ (or something equivalent, where $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the sign function, taking the value $1$ when the argument is greater than $0$, and the value $-1$ when its argument is less than $0$: the value when the argument is exactly $0$ is usually taken to be $0$, but it doesn't matter here, because your expression isn't defined when $y = 60$ anyway.